# Bad CPU type in executable : error pop up when run flutter commands

Tags: flutter, dart

```
macbook@macbooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter doctor
/Users/macbook/Downloads/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 235: /Users/macbook/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Bad CPU type in executable
```

A sudden error on the flutter terminal after converting into bash.

currently, I convert the bash terminal to `zsh` terminal. still, the same error is showing while running flutter commands.

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps:

```
$ nano ~/.zshrc
```

add these lines to `.zhrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/dart-sdk/bin"
```

run this command:

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

and finally, check everything is fine:

```
$ flutter doctor
```

Answer (score -1):

> The error message "Bad CPU type in executable" indicates that there is
> a mismatch between the architecture of the Flutter/Dart executable and
> the architecture of your machine's CPU. This commonly occurs when
> you're trying to run an executable compiled for a different
> architecture.

Since you mentioned that ***the error started happening after converting your terminal from Bash to Zsh,*** it's possible that the shell change might have affected your environment settings. It's essential to ensure that your Flutter installation and Dart SDK are compatible with your system architecture.

**Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:**

1. Check System Architecture:

- Open Terminal (Zsh) and run the following command to check your Mac's architecture: `uname -m`
- Common architectures are x86_64 (Intel-based) and arm64 (Apple Silicon/M1).

2. Reinstall Flutter:

- Download the latest version of Flutter for your architecture from the official website (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install).
- Extract the downloaded ZIP file to a suitable location.
  Update your PATH variable to point to the new Flutter installation.

3. Verify Dart SDK:

- Make sure the Dart SDK bundled with Flutter is compatible with your system architecture.
- Check the dart-sdk directory in your Flutter installation to see if it matches your system architecture.

4. Update Environment Variables:

- Ensure that the environment variables are correctly set in your Zsh configuration (e.g., .zshrc or .zprofile).
- Update the PATH variable to point to the correct Dart SDK and Flutter locations.

5. Restart Terminal:

- After making changes to your environment settings, close and reopen your terminal for the changes to take effect.

6. Confirm Architecture:

- After setting up everything correctly, run flutter doctor again to verify that the error is resolved.

> If you are using an Apple Silicon/M1 Mac, you should be using the
> arm64 version of Flutter and the Dart SDK. If you are using an
> Intel-based Mac, you should use the x86_64 version.